# Scroll bar is not showing the whole screen

Tags: android

I have created a scroll bar using the following XML:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--added more layout inside this-->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now when I'm running my app its showing black screen below the layout if my app is not filled the whole screen.

Does anybody know why this might be happening?

Comment: It will be better if u post ur whole XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ScrollView` height is wrapping to the content of the `LinearLayout`.

Try changing your XML to this:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--added more layout inside this-->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now your `ScrollView` should use the entire screen, instead of only taking up enough to hold your `LinearLayout`.